# Prove that a sequence in $A$ that converges in $x\in X$ $\Rightarrow$ $x\in Cl(A)$

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification

Let $X$ be a space and $A\subseteq X$ if it exists a sequence of points of $A$ that converges to $x\in X$, show that $x\in Cl(A)$

---

Let $x_n,n\in \mathbb{N}$  be a sequence of $ A$. From the definition of convergence, for every  open neighborhood $U_x$, that contains $x$ it exists a $n_0\in \mathbb{N}$ such that for every $n\geq n_0, n\in \mathbb{N}$ $x_n \in U_x$, because for every $n\in \mathbb{N}$ $x_n\in A$ I get that $U_x\cap A\setminus \{x\}\neq \varnothing $ $\Rightarrow U_x\cap A\neq  \{x\}\neq  \varnothing $

that means $x\in Cl(A)$

Comment: In order to show $x$ belongs to the closure you only need to show that any open neighborhood of $x$ intersects $A$, not that it intersects $A\setminus\{x\}$. After all, $x_n$ might be the constant sequence $x$.

Comment: @Mark, I know that's what I have shown.

Comment: @Mark if it's the constant sequence, then the limit point $x\in A$

Comment: I just don't understand why you wrote $U_x\cap A\ne\{x\}$. It's just that $U_x\cap A$ is not empty.

Comment: I agree with @Mark your prove ends here "I get $\color{red}{U_x\cap A\ne\emptyset}$" since it is not true that $U_x\cap A\setminus \{x\}\neq \emptyset$ for this it is necessary to have a non-constant sequence, but this is not a hypothesis.

Comment: @Zaragosa OP probably uses the definition that the closure of $A$ is $A$ plus all its limit points? So he want to show $x$ is a limit point of $A$. But in that case you need to separate the case $x\in A$ first.

Comment: I also thought about it but if so there would be some restriction for the succession because the constant succession destroys your argument. @lupusnox could you put the definition you are using for $\operatorname{cl}(A)$?